# Additive commutator transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}.$ Let $V = M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{C})$ be the vector space of complex square matrices. For each $A, B \in V,$ define$$T_{(A,B)}(v) = (AB-BA)v.$$ Then $T$ is linear.

(1) Let $$N = \ \cap_{i=1}^{n}\cap_{j=1}^n\mbox{ker}(T_{(A^i,B^j)}).$$ Verify that $N$ is invariant under each of $A,B.$

(2) $A, B$ has a common eigenvector if and only if $N$ is not a trivial suspace of $V$.

I dont understand what $(1)$ asks ? Invariant ? Does it mean for $N$ is independent of choice of $A,B$ ? That is, for any pairs of matrices$ (A,B) , (C,D)$, it will gives the same $N$ ?

Answer (score 0):

$N$ is invariant under $A$ if and only if $Ax\in N$ for all $x\in N$.

Take $x\in N$. Then we know
$$
A^iB^j x = B^jA^ix \quad \forall i,j = 1\dots n.
$$
Due to Caley-Hamilton theorem, all powers of $A$ are a linear combination of $A^0,A^1\dots A^{n-1}$. It follows
$$
A^iB^j x = B^jA^ix \quad \forall i,j \in\mathbb N.
$$
Now fix $i,j$. Then
$$
(A^iB^j)Ax =  A^{i+1}B^jx= B^j A^iAx = (B^jA^i)Ax
$$
hence $A\in \ker(T_{A^i,B^j})$. This holds for all $i,j$, hence $Ax\in N$.

Comment: So what is “invariant” in this sense ?